# Laravel pivot table count in where clause of a scope method

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Following are my model's relationship:

Concerts

Customers

Venues belongs to concert (One to Many)

Timeslots belongs to venue (One to Many)

Tickets (Many to Many of Customers & Timeslots)

I'm trying to get the count of a many to many relationship of timeslot as part of a where clause in a scope method of my model Venue.

```
public function scopeGetConcertVenuesThatHaveSlotsRemains($query, $concert_id)
{
    $query->where('concert_id', $concert_id);
    $query->whereHas('timeslots', function ($query2) {
        $query2->where('slots', '>=', "Ticket.counts"); 
    });
}
```

How do I get the Ticket.counts value?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer myself.

```
public function scopeGetConcertVenuesThatHaveSlotsRemains($query, $concert_id)
{
    $query->where('concert_id', $concert_id);
    $query->whereHas('timeslots', function ($query2) {
        $query2->withCount('customers')->whereColumn('slots', '>', 'customers_count'); 
    });
}
```